# Bullets in beamer bibliography overlap with frame theme. How to remove bullets and/or correctly indent bibliography?

Tags: latex, beamer

I am having an issue in my beamer presentation where the bullets in the bibliography are overlapping with the frame theme. Circled in red is the overlap I want removed: [image: Circled in red is the overlapping bullet. I either want to remove it or indent the bibliography.]

[Here](https://github.com/jec52011/log_file/blob/main/output.log) is the .log file. Below is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize{}}
\bibliography{main.bib}


% Start presentation
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide Title}
\begin{itemize}\small
    \item Blah blah blah blah blah.\footcite{stanojevic2016approx}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What I noticed is that when I use `\usepackage{biblatex}` instead of `\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}` the bullet overlapping problem goes away.  However, I want to use `style=authortitle` because I want `\footcite{}` to be styled this way. **How can I either remove the bullets and/or indent the bibliography to address the overlap, all while keeping the `\footcite{}` styling?**

Comment: I can't reproduce if I puzzle together your code fragments into a compilable example https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZPll.png Can you a) make a [mre] and b) show your .log file to check if all your packages are up-to-date?

Comment: Ok, I updated the code block to a compilable example.  On my end I am still seeing the issue.  I have the .log file, but I'm trying to figure out how to show it on here.

Comment: If the .log file is too long to paste it directly into your question, try pastebin.com, github or similar services

Comment: While waiting to get the log file, a couple of unrelated comments: in biblatex, you should use `\addbibresource` instead of `\bibliography` and the `{}` after `\scriptsize` are superflous

Comment: Ok, I added a link to the .log file, just before the code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was been fixed in [2a81ef0](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/2a81ef0c0172a4ba7ee11676a177c7f6fd21cf3d) . You'll need to upgrade to at least beamer v3.59.

(better update to version v3.60, once it is available at CTAN or the development version from https://github.com/josephwright/beamer because this includes a fix to a follow up problem)

---

For the poor souls stuck with an outdated texlive version from overleaf:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize{}}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
  \mode<presentation>{%
      \newlength{\beamer@bibiconwidth}
      \settowidth\beamer@bibiconwidth{\usebeamertemplate*{bibliography item}}
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\beamer@bibiconwidth}
      \addtolength{\labelwidth}{2\labelsep}
      \addtolength{\bibhang}{\labelsep}
  }
\makeatother


% Start presentation
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide Title}
\begin{itemize}\small
    \item Blah blah blah blah blah.\footcite{knuth:ct}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This might seem like a silly question, but if I am using overleaf, how can I change the version of beamer?